# Show that the absolute maximum of $f(x, y) = \frac{(ax+by+c)^2}{x^2+y^2+1}$ is $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

I got this question on my exam today: show that the function $f(x, y) =  \dfrac{(ax+by+c)^2}{x^2+y^2+1}$ has an absolute maximum whose value is $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$.

I tried setting the gradient to the zero vector, but it was really hairy. Expanding the numerator also does not seem to help. There also doesn't seem to be any type of coordinate transformation that would help.

The gradient:
$$\nabla f(x, y) = -2 \frac{a x + b y + c}{(x^2 + y^2 + 1)^2}\langle x (b y + c) - a (y^2 + 1), y (a x + c) - b (x^2 + 1)\rangle$$

Comment: You could use polar coordinates so the denominator would only depend on $r$, but I’m not certain that it’s worth it.

Comment: Please include the work you claim you did in your post?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK... I realize now that expected answer was through the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
$$\textbf{X} = \langle x, y, 1\rangle $$
$$\textbf{a} = \langle a, b, c\rangle $$
$$\textbf{X}\cdot\textbf{a} \le |\textbf{X}|\cdot|\textbf{a}| $$
And this is equal to:
$$ax+by+c \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2+1} \cdot \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
so
$$\frac{(ax+by+c)^2}{x^2+y^2+1} \le  a^2+b^2+c^2$$

Comment: I suppose this only establishes an upper bound, though...

Comment: Cleaner to consider $\frac{(ax+by+cz)^2}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$  for which the critical points are eigenvectors of the Hessian matrix of $(ax+by+cz)^2$

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Regarding your comment that it defines only an upper bound, remember that equality in CS is reached when vectors are colinear i.e. $(x,y,1)=\lambda(a,b,c)\implies \lambda=\frac 1c\implies x=\frac ac,y=\frac bc$ as in my answer. And the case $c=0$ poses the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can notice more or less easily that $f(\frac ac,\frac bc)=a^2+b^2+c^2$.

Since you are hinted that it is the maximum you can set $\begin{cases}x=X+\frac ac\\y=Y+\frac bc\end{cases}$ and calculate (I skip some details...)

$\begin{align}(a^2+b^2+c^2)-f(x,y)
&=\dfrac{(b^2+c^2)X^2+(a^2+c^2)Y^2-2abXY}{x^2+y^2+1}\\\\
&=\dfrac{(bX-aY)^2+c^2(X^2+Y^2)}{x^2+y^2+1}\\\\
&\ge 0\end{align}$

The case $c=0$ still need to be handled separately. It is a bit more difficult because in this case the maximum is reached at infinity.